# Command Line API and waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new to objective c.  i am using following code to execute command line API in objective c. code is working fine for me. but why this code is using NSRunLoop?

```
-(void)uploadData
{
setenv([@"PASSWORD" UTF8String], [mPassword UTF8String], 1);
[task setLaunchPath:executablePathRoot];
[task setArguments:array];
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSPipe *errorPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
[task setStandardError:errorPipe];
//keeps your log where it belongs
//[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

NSFileHandle *outFile = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
NSFileHandle *errFile = [errorPipe fileHandleForReading];


[task launch];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(terminated:)
                                             name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification
                                           object:task];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(outData:)
                                             name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                           object:outFile];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(errData:)
                                             name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                           object:errFile];


[outFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
[errFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
while(!terminated) 
{
    if (![[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]) 
    {
        break;
    }
    [pool release];
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
}
[pool release];

[self appendDataFrom:outFile to:output];
[self appendDataFrom:errFile to:error];
//[task waitUntilExit];
[task release];
}


-(void) outData: (NSNotification *) notification
{
NSLog(@"outData");
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = (NSFileHandle*) [notification object];
[self appendDataFrom:fileHandle to:output];
[fileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify]; //Checks to see if data is available in a background thread.
}


-(void) errData: (NSNotification *) notification
{
NSLog(@"errData");
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = (NSFileHandle*) [notification object];
[self appendDataFrom:fileHandle to:output];
[fileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
}

- (void) terminated: (NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"Task terminated");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
terminated =YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to make the method uploadData synchronous. The execution cannot quit the `while` loop until the `terminated` flag is set YES. The following call

```
[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]
```

allows the app to process other events. So, when the `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification` received the terminated flag will be changed and the while loop finishes.

However, there is no need to allocate an autorelease pool here. Also, the code is excessive. It can much simpler:

```
while(!terminated) 
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Update: Taking into account ughoavgfhw's comments, let's make the call even safer by including the result of runMode: beforeDate: into the condition.

```
while(!terminated && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
```

Comment: I disagree on your modifications to the run loop code. You should always use an autorelease pool around a run loop, since you never know how much data will be created and autoreleased in an iteration. It is also proper to break the loop if `runMode:beforeDate:` returns `NO`, since that indicates an error (or no input sources, which is an error since the pipes should be connected to it).

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I agree that an autorelease pool may be used there if we know what we are going to optimise. However, I am positive we should not use it always as a preventive means just because we do not know how much data will be created. We already have an autorelease pool in the current thread, it will do the job.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I agree, the negative result of runMode:beforeDate: should be handled.